# input in C program

Tags: c

I wrote a program to generate monomials and polynomial and print monomials and polynomial. The data are input from keyboard. For example, first input the number of groups of data 3, then input the data: 1,3,2,4,3,6,3,4,2 (each group has 3 elements). I need output monomial Y^{1}*{2,3}Y^{4}*{3,6}Y^{3}_{4,2}. My program can work. But the output is not correct. I think the problem of the program is in the following part. I think the scanf is not good in the following. Are there other better input method to fix this problem? The whole program is in http://hi.baidu.com/lijr03/blog/item/51e17b0c63614bc863d98629.html

```
monomial create_monomial(int number) /* create a monomial */
{

   monomial m,s;
   monomial p;
   int i;


   printf("Please input the parameters (for example,  2, 2, 3 denotes the monomial P^{2}_{2,3}). The first subscripts i's of P's should be in increase order.");
   m=(monomial)malloc(sizeof(monomial_node));
   m->head=m->tail=(monomial)malloc(sizeof(monomial_node));

   if(m->head==NULL)
   {
     return NULL;
   }

   m->head->next=m->tail;

   m->tail->next=NULL;

   p=(monomial)malloc(sizeof(monomial_node));

   m->head->next=p;

   p->next=m->tail;   

   scanf("%d", &((p->y).l)); 
   scanf("%d", &((p->y).i));
   scanf("%d", &((p->y).k));

  if(number > 1)
  {
   for(i=0;i<number-1;i++)

   {

    s=(monomial)malloc(sizeof(monomial_node));

    scanf("%d", &((s->y).l)); 
    scanf("%d", &((s->y).i));
    scanf("%d", &((s->y).k));

    s->next=p->next;     /* insert the node a */

    p->next=s;

    free(s);            

   }
  }
   return m;
}
```

Comment: Did you already post this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444537/code-cannot-work

Comment: Don't cast the return value of `malloc`. Casting is, at best, redundant and may hide an error the compiler would have caught without the cast. Also what are `monomial` and `monomial_node`? Are they equivalent types?

Comment: @pmg, they are not equivalent. They are defined as <pre> typedef struct node /*a node denotes a P_{i,k}^{l}*/

{

 int l,i,k;

} node;

 

 

typedef struct monomial_node /* a monomial denotes a monomial P_{i,k}^{l} \cdots P_{i',k'}^{l'} */

{

 node y;

 int coeff;         /* coeff is s(m_r) */

 struct monomial_node *next; 

 struct monomial_node *head;

 struct monomial_node *tail; 

} monomial_node, *monomial;

 

 

 <code>

Comment: @pmg, they are defined in the link above.

Comment: Ah! typedefs hiding the pointer-ness of the type, ugh! I like to `malloc` simply with the size of the object itself: `p = malloc(sizeof *p);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `free(s)` means that you are destroying the monomial that you've just created.  The pointer that you create above it (from `p`) means that you'll be pointing to a potentially invalid bit of memory when you process `m`.

Comment: in the loop, I s is assigned memory again by s=(monomial)malloc(sizeof(monomial_node));

Comment: @math 123 - As it stands the free is deleting an object that you are still pointing to; the fact you reuse the variable s is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf` is a fine choice, but it can be a little peculiar.  I think in this case you need a scanf format like "%d,%d,%d".  The best thing to do, however, is write a small simple C program that just inputs the data and experiment with that.  It would look something like

```
 int main(){
     int x, y, z ;

     scanf("%d,%d,%d", &x, &y, &z);
     printf("%d,%d,%d\n", x,y,z);
     return 0;
 }
```

Once you have that working, getting the real program to work should be straightforward.

Comment: I know this. But I need many of x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,... They are input by a loop. Then there are some problems.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown what the erroneous output is I can only make an educated guess on exactly what the problem might be, but in addition to the incorrect `scanf()` calls and the call to `free` that is deleting the additional allocated nodes in your list, you have "empty" nodes for `head` and `tail`.  So when you traverse your linked list, you will need to take into account that the `head` and `tail` nodes are empty, otherwise you're going to get some odd values for those nodes since they are uninitialized.